# Show running windows in launcher quicklist?

Tags: unity, launcher

I love the quicklist for launchers, and that it shows if multiple windows are open via the arrow indicators. However, it doesn't seem to list the running in the quicklist interface. Is there anyway to have the Unity Launcher list the running windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*As of yet there is none*. The quicklists don't update that fast (only after unity --replace or similar events). So it's a technical problem.

But that is a feature most users eagerly await. Canonical will eventually give in to this demand. It should would have reduced a great lot of disappointment with unity if showing a quicklist of open windows had been the default behaviour on mouseover from the start.

Comment: citation needed?